# Calculate offset given distorted ellipse on sphere

Tags: 3d, geometry, computer-vision, vision, geometry-surface

I have a circle moving on a spherical surface. If the camera angle is fixed, is there a way to calculate the original circle's offset from the centre given the distorted ellipse formed when the circle moves to the edge of the sphere(as seen from the camera)?
I've looked into Listing's plane and the Tissot directrix(because I'm working with eyeball rotation), but neither seems to provide a clear solution to this. I've also looked papers regarding eyeball roation but they seem to focus on the physiological aspects rather than the math of the movement.[image: Listing's Plane]
In other words: In the picture above, given one of the outer nine images *as well as* the middle one, I want to calculate how much the circle(i.e. iris) has moved/rotated from its position in the middle picture. I assume it has to do with comparing the distorted ellipse with the circle, but I can't seem to find out how. Is there some formula for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the position of the center of the ellipse, the position of the center of the pupil or the position of the apex (projection of the pupil center onto the globe) ? Considering a cross section by a "theta" plane will make things much simpler.

Comment: I'm looking for the center of the ellipse, to be precise.

Comment: Do you know that the center of the ellipse is not the exact center of the pupil ?

Comment: Did you try to look a the cross-section ?

Comment: I'm not sure how a cross section would help. Then what other measure is there to calculate the exact center of the pupil? I've tried searching for methods, to no avail.

Comment: it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

While iris is fully visible (lie in the nearest hemisphere), you can consider it as plane circle object, so it's image is right ellipse.

Let's `Phi` is tilt angle of eye axis (drawn at your picture) and `Theta` is angle of eye rotation about this axis

```
semimajor axis a is equal to iris radius R
semiminor axis b is equal to R * Cos(Theta), 
      Theta = Arrcos(b/a)
Phi = Arctan(a axis tilt angle)
```

To choose exact sign of Theta value, you need also to determine position of elipse relative to big white circle center (the first and the last images are for -45 and + 45 degrees)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I do have a few clarifications to ask of you, though - I didn't understand how you propose to calculate the angle Phi? And I understand phi, but conceptually, what is theta? Where does the rotation about the axis take place? Isn't there only one rotation involved(ie, that of the eyeball, as in the 9 pictures)?

Comment: There is only one rotation, but it is about some arbitrary axis. You can reach the same result with two rotation about coordinate axes (for example, about OX, then about OY). As example, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula with three rotations about axes. (Your case is more constrained). But what result did you want to get?